# jQuery UI Dialog with customized data call

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, spring-mvc

I have not used jQuery that much and I am trying to stay away from using regular javascript since i have to support many browsers and i want to learn.  I have a Spring MVC writing a table of elements including a few attributes being populated like ${tt.id} etc.. I have to construct a popup that can display all the details and some others that arent displayed in the table itself in a popup.  I have made the framework for the popup and have the div assigned, is there an easy way to address the jquery call for the onclick to display the popup to take an attribute value such as ${tt.id} as to avoid redundancy of code?

```
$(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
    height:200, and some other size attributes here...
    autoOpen:false
    });
    $(".table a").click(function() {
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
        });
  });
```

That is the code i have now so you can see im attaching it properly to the  tags in the table but rather than make 20 of these hidden divs (which i could) i would like to make it smarter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Man, if i understood your problem, you can solve it like this:

You can attack, for each table row, something like this: `<a class="foo" id="theObjId"></a>`. And, says to jquery, that every click, will generate a ajax request, passing the id attribute. So, the response will update the popup div.

Comment: I am just not sure how to do the jQuery script so that it can reference theObjId which is the issue I was having.  I was having a hard time finding an example of it so that i could wrap my head around how to construct it properly.

Comment: If you know a little of Jquery, this will help you in your thread http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/